# How routing works on Internet

Tags: router, internet, routing

When computer A (e.g. in Paris) wants to send e.g a HTTP request to server B (e.g. in Berlin), then as I understand, (after all upper layers) computer A has to send an Ethernet frame to the default gateway that gives access to the Internet (so router).

But how can the router (e.g. this simple router at home bought for 30$) know all appropriate hops that will lead the HTTP request to the appropriate machine?

I know about static and dynamic routing, but we still need some "initial routings" (as far as I understand). So how is this magic that creates that "initial routing data"? And if the whole process of sending packets between different machines from different networks depends only on routing, then why do we use ISP? And how can the router know all appropriate routes to the next hop (and how does it know the hop will be appropriate), isn't it too much data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how the router (e.g. this simple router in home bought for 30$) can know all appropriate hops that will lead the HTTP request to appropriate machine?

In your case, as a residential customer – it doesn't. Your $30 router only knows *very* minimal routes: one to your LAN, and another to "the rest of the world" (default route), not too different from what your computer has. (You can take a look at the router's own status page; often it will have a "Routing table" section *somewhere.*)

Instead you usually rely on the *next* routers, the ones at your ISP, to know the full Internet routing table. (Usually the ISP's network is large enough that the job is split; the 2nd hop deals with internal routes to ISP's other customers, while the 3rd hop deals with external connections and the full Internet routing table, roughly speaking.)

However, larger customers, e.g. medium/large institutions, *do* receive a full BGP feed from their ISP if they want one and if they have the hardware for it – and especially if they use multiple ISPs so that they get to choose "best" routes from each. (That is to say, it's not restricted to "ISPs" as such, anyone can have access to it.)

Finally, on the Internet, routers don't know *all* appropriate hops; they only know the *immediate next* hop for any given destination. The sender doesn't have the ability to specify the full path even if they wanted to<sup>1</sup>. This means that your $30 router only needs to know a single "next hop" that'll handle everything, and doesn't need to care about what happens beyond that.

<sup>1</sup> (This is not universal for all routing, e.g. routers *within* an ISP might use MPLS to precompute an exact path throughout the ISP's network, but it is specifically true for the path *between* networks on the Internet.)

> I know about static and dynamic routing, but we still need some "initial routings" (as far I understand). So how is called this magic that creates that "initial routing data"?

The most basic "initial" routes come from direct connections – when two networks physically connect their routers together, the interconnection ends up being a tiny subnet on its own, where each router automatically knows how to reach the other by nature of being in the same subnet (exactly like how a regular LAN subnet works, except smaller; usually a /30 or /31 for IPv4).

```
+-- ISP 1 --+                 +-- ISP 2 --+
|           |                 |           |
|  Router1 ~~~{192.0.2.64/30}~~~ Router2  |
|           |                 |           |
+-----------+                 +-----------+
```

Once such a connection exists, the routers can speak IP to each other – and they can use each other as a "next-hop" or "gateway" for additional routes, if any were configured.

When connecting independent networks (between ISPs or such), the operators will usually set up BGP between the routers to automate the route exchange. (Each router will be set up to announce the operator's whole network, e.g. Router2 would learn "<ISP1network>/16 via <Router1>".) These BGP announcements propagate to all other routers around the world that are also running BGP, building up the "global routing table".

Connections between routers within the same network work the same way – building on directly-connected subnets to establish initial communication, which can be used for static routes or for dynamic protocols like Babel or OSPF. An institution might use OSPF to distribute precise subnet routes across its network, then BGP to advertise an aggregated route to the Internet.

> And how the router can know all appropriate routes to next hop (and how know the hop will be appropriate),

As shown above, direct routes to "next hops" are automatically known, while routes to further destinations are received through a dynamic routing protocol (BGP between networks, OSPF or Babel or iBGP or IS-IS internally within a network).

Selecting the "best" route is the main job of that routing protocol. Depending on the protocol it might be simply based on hop count (shortest route = preferred), or might consider relative "costs" of each path, or might prefer a certain path by operator-set policy.

> isn't it too much data?

It can be. Even with aggregation, the IPv4 routing table has in fact [grown](https://bgp.potaroo.net/as2.0/bgp-active.html) so large that it has increasingly reached the limits of older routers several times (e.g. when it has reached 512k routes, and then 1M routes – just search for the "`512k bgp`" day).

The IPv6 routing table is much smaller – a $30 router could not handle it, but a $200 router probably could.

*(Part of this is due to IPv4 address scarcity; operators can no longer obtain an IPv4 address block that would be large enough and are forced to collect lots of tiny address blocks instead, sometimes resulting in hundreds of routes for the same operator. Whereas in IPv6 they can easily get just a single large chunk.)*

> And if whole process of sending packets between different machines from different networks depends only on routing, then why we use ISP?

ISPs also handle the physical interconnections – not just for customers, but also the (nowadays 100+ Gbps) links *between* ISPs. They also handle the massive routing tables so that your $30 router won't have to, and in general are responsible for making the network run more efficiently than a random mesh of links. More or less the same reasons why you have telephone operators instead of running wires directly to each of your friends.

You *can* build your own small network without "ISPs" as such – there exist several "community networks" built over radio links, for example (Freifunk and similar), and as mentioned earlier many large institutions do run BGP all on their own and are on par with ISPs. (After all, initially there weren't *any* ISPs, just a bunch of universities and research labs.)

In the end it's really just a matter of getting the physical links set up, and distributing the routes. Once it grows sufficiently large and/or complex, though, some of the more-capable participants will inevitably become "ISPs" for those who can no longer participate directly.

> then as I understand, (after all upper layers) the computer A has to send Ethernet frame to default gateway that gives access to Internet (so router).

One last note; when discussing the Internet, the focus is not on Ethernet frames but on IP packets, as that's the end-to-end message that needs to be delivered, while Ethernet framing only delivers it over that particular link.

The same IP packet could end up being routed over an Ethernet link, then over an ATM circuit (ADSL was originally IP-over-ATM), over an X.25 call (in the early days), over SDH/SONET (used to be the most common choice for large carrier networks), over RS-232 serial (dial-up modems and early forms of cell phone "tethering"), over carrier pigeons, and so on, with its framing being reconstructed on every hop.

(And although there *are* routing protocols that deal with Ethernet L2 addressing and systems that route and forward whole Ethernet frames, they're only used internally within a single network, and they remain invisible to IP and to the Internet as a whole; such a routed Ethernet connection would still appear as a single hop to IP.)

Comment: Nice. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2549

Comment: Many (if not most) consumer-grade router has only "Information of Internet / WAN Connectivtiy" where its default gateway is shown. "Route table", if any, will only list the static routes the owner has added.

Answer (score 4):

So your question is awfully broad as stated, so I'll barely scratch the surface, but I think the thing you are missing is that the route is not decided in advance (in fact multiple packets in a connection may take widly different paths from source to destination), and no one party has visibility on the entire path taken (they only see the fragment of the path they occupy).

instead each hop on the path is determined exclusively between the hop-from and hop-to routers.
consider this path from 192.168.0.7 to 10.1.2.3:

```
Router1(192.168.0.1)  doesn't know 10.0.0.0/8. uses default route via gateway 192.168.5.1. 
Router2(192.168.5.1) knows that 10.0.0.0/8 is available on gateway 10.0.0.1. 
Router3(10.0.0.1) knows that 10.1.0.0/16 is available on gateway 10.1.0.1.
Router4(10.1.0.1) knows that 10.1.2.0/24 is available on gateway 10.1.2.1.
Router5(10.1.2.1) delivers the packet to 10.1.2.3/32.
```

This is a very simplistic and generic example, and it gets very complicated, but notice how the closer you get to the destination, the more specific the information you have on exactly how to reach the destination.

so in your example, the system in Britain only needs to know how to get to its ISP interconnects. the ISP only needs to know how to get to a connected partner on mainland Europe. that partner only needs to know how to get to a German partner network. on and on it goes through the region, ISP, etc, until you arrive at the remote destination.

Generally this is called [Route Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernetwork), and allows the giant routers at the core of the Internet to reach any destination, without hosting and maintaining millions of routes.

as for why you need an ISP, its more or less the same reason that you need an electric provider to get power to your PC. if your house is not connected up to the electric companies distribution network, there isn't electricity coming into the houses, so if you plug in a light, it won't turn on. ISPs have upstream interconnects to the larger networks or to the backbone itself, so without one, you don;t have anyone to send/recieve traffic to/from.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand well. So my poor router in home just know the route to ISP's router which can know even routes for whole Internet (at least big piece of it)?

Comment: yeah that is more or less it. the upstream routers know the routes they need to know for their purpose, so that no one router needs to know too many routes.

Comment: @Szyszka947 You can think of it this way: routers don't have to know the whole route to the destination. It's sufficient if they know a router that is one hop closer to the destination.

Answer (score 3):

The $30 home router does a lot less then you may think. Cutting it down to its minimal requirement it needs to

1. Be able to read the ethernet frame and identify the destination ip of the traffic (and src ip and source and destination if its doing NAT which it most likely is)
2. Know what devices/IPs are reachable on its LAN port - which is where netmasks come in
3. Know which router knows where all other traffic goes and how to reach it - ie **the default route**  Importantly it does not need to know anything about dynamic routing or routers other then the ones it directly talks to.

You can see the information in 3 and for by looking at its route table (similar to the one on your computer, except the interface of the default route - 0.0.0.0/0 - is associated with a different interface.)  It varies from router to router, but if you can access a console on it - "route -n" or "ip route show" often show this table.

For routers handling NAT - most small routers - they additionally need to maintain a lookup table with at least 4 pieces of information - source and destination ip and ports.  It then looks at each packet flowing from lan to wan or wan to lan and rewrites the source or target IP with the IP so it can share a single "real" IP among multiple computers.  It only needs to know about recent connections - so not the whole internet.

(Its worth pointing out that really cheap routers sometimes appear buggy because they fail to maintain a routing table large enough for the number of lan clients.